# $.each has one more item than for loop

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I'm trying to get data from a mysql database via php, encoding it as JSON, then parsing it into an array that displays data in a bar chart.

If I explicitly declare values, such as:

```
var data = new Array ();
data.push ([[5,66],[6,65],[7,68],[8,67],[9,64],[10,68],[11,73],[12,66],[13,70],[14,72],[15,74],[16,75],[17,67],[18,67],[19,39],[20,25]]);
```

This works.
[image]
[image]

If I create a loop, such as:

```
var data = new Array ();
var namespacedata = [];
for (var j=5; j<20; j++) {
    namespacedata.push([j,66]);
}
data.push(namespacedata);
```

This also works.
  [image]

If i use the console in chrome along with some logging, I can see the array being passed is 15 elements long:
[image]

However, when I try to parse my json array, which looks like this coming from php:

> [{"NAMESPACE":"5","used":"66"},{"NAMESPACE":"6","used":"64"},{"NAMESPACE":"7","used":"68"},{"NAMESPACE":"8","used":"67"},{"NAMESPACE":"9","used":"64"},{"NAMESPACE":"10","used":"67"},{"NAMESPACE":"11","used":"72"},{"NAMESPACE":"12","used":"67"},{"NAMESPACE":"13","used":"70"},{"NAMESPACE":"14","used":"71"},{"NAMESPACE":"15","used":"74"},{"NAMESPACE":"16","used":"74"},{"NAMESPACE":"17","used":"67"},{"NAMESPACE":"18","used":"70"},{"NAMESPACE":"19","used":"41"},{"NAMESPACE":"20","used":"25"}]

using this code:

```
var data = new Array ();
var namespacedata = [];
$.getJSON("resources/get_namespace_usage.php", function(result) {
    $.each(result, function(i, item) {
        namespacedata.push([Number(item.NAMESPACE),Number(item.used)]);
    });

    console.log(namespacedata);
    data.push(namespacedata);
    console.log(data);
});
```

I get a 16 element array, and the graph doesn't work
[image]

[image]

As far as I can tell, everything looks like it should, if I inspect the 2D arrays inside the console, the data looks correct, yet I can't understand why I'm getting an extra element, and why the graph doesn't work.    I've tried splicing the array, that doesn't work.

What is so fundamentally different between these three implementations (two that work, one that doesn't?)    I suppose I could do a for loop given a fixed number (j=5; j<20;j++), but this doesn't scale well, and will be messier than getting the $.each to work.

Thanks in advance!

Edit: full bar.js file:

```
$(function () {
    var data = new Array ();
    var ds = new Array();
    var namespacedata = [];

    $.getJSON("resources/get_namespace_usage.php", function(result) {
        $.each(result, function(i, item) {
            namespacedata.push([Number(item.NAMESPACE),Number(item.used)]);
        });
        data.push(namespacedata);
        console.log(data);
    });

    for (var i=0, j=data.length; i<j; i++) {

        ds.push({
            data:data[i],
            grid:{
                hoverable:false
            },
            bars: {
                show: true,
                barWidth: 0.8,
                order: 1,
                align: "center",
                lineWidth: 0.5,
                fillColor: { colors: [ { opacity: 0.75 }, { opacity: 1 } ] }
            }
        });
    }

    var somePlot = $.plot($("#bar-chart"), ds, {
        colors: ["#F90"],
        yaxis: {
            min: 0,
            max: 100,
        },
        xaxis: {
            ticks: [[5,"NS5"],[6,"NS6"],[7,"NS7"],[8,"NS8"],[9,"NS9"],[10,"NS10"],[11,"NS11"],[12,"NS12"],[13,"NS13"],[14,"NS14"],[15,"NS15"],[16,"NS16"],[17,"NS17"],[18,"NS18"],[19,"D2C"],[20,"BPN"]]
        }
    });

    var ctx = somePlot.getCanvas().getContext("2d"); // get the context
    var data = somePlot.getData()[0].data;  // get your series data
    var xaxis = somePlot.getXAxes()[0]; // xAxis
    var yaxis = somePlot.getYAxes()[0]; // yAxis
    var offset = somePlot.getPlotOffset(); // plots offset
    ctx.font = "14px 'Segoe UI'"; // set a pretty label font
    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
        var text = data[i][1] + '';
        var metrics = ctx.measureText(text);
        var xPos = (xaxis.p2c(data[i][0])+offset.left) - metrics.width/2; // place  it in the middle of the bar
        var yPos = yaxis.p2c(data[i][1]) + offset.top + 13; // place at top of bar, slightly up
        ctx.fillText(text, xPos, yPos);
    }
});
```

Comment: The array you posted as "coming from PHP" has 16 entries in it.

Comment: Note that your loop condition was `j < 20`, not `j <= 20`.

Comment: When are you calling the function that plots the data? You need to do that in the `$.getJSON` callback, otherwise you'll plot the data before the response comes.

Comment: @[pointy the plot comes after the each loop is run.. I'll amend the question with the entire .js file

Comment: @barmar  can you post your answer as comment?  I ended up moving the end of the success brackets to the end of the file, causing the plotting to be performed on success, graphs work now.   Thanks!

Comment: Answers can't be added to questions that have been closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a problem with `$.each`. Check the response coming from PHP.

Add `console.log(result)` just before the `$.each` line.

Also, note that [`Array#push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push) adds its argument to the array. So the line `data.push(namespacedata);` will add a single item to `data` containing the 16 elements. If you wanted to append the 16 items to `data`, then you should look in to [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat)

Comment: The graphing library he's using apparently expects the data to be a sub-array, so `data.push(namespacedata)` is correct. It works in the earlier examples.

Comment: Ah, ignore my last paragraph then. Thanks!